# Why Post Was Deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I posted a reply to an old post on Psalm 22:16 this morning, and it was deleted? Is this not allowed? can I post it elsewhere? Thanks Andy

[Location of Dead Sea Scroll with Psalm 22 verse 17 - They pierced my hands and my feet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64954/location-of-dead-sea-scroll-with-psalm-22-verse-17-they-pierced-my-hands-and-m/94226#94226)

Comment: It could be posted as an answer to [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/4489/21321) on the Biblical Hermeneutics site.

Answer (score 7):

Echoing DoubleAA in a comment on this post:

> Your post didn't answer the question at all... Extensive argument that Jews corrupted Tanakh to remove proofs of Christianity is not a link to the dead sea scrolls.