# Why doesn’t a poster get notified when his post is deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers, deleted-questions, deletions

I’ve noticed several questions lately regarding people asking, some more politely than others, why their posts randomly disappeared:

[Why did my answer disappear?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4736/9682)

[How do I contact the moderators here?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735/9682)

[Why Post Was Deleted?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4730/9682)

In light of all this recent activity, and I think it’s important to note that these are all new users: Is there a way to notify users A) that their post was deleted, but more importantly: B) *why* their post was deleted?

As an example, take the second question above. IndependentThinker’s answer was deleted as not answering the question, and he had no idea that it wasn’t a good answer. Not only should such answers be flagged as such, but they should detail to the OP *why* they don’t answer the question, in order that the OP can be given a chance to fix their post before it’s deleted, or at least that they can learn how the site works better and not make the same mistake again.

Comment: Three out of four of IndependentThinker's deleted answers did have comments on them...

Comment: The notification issue is an old one https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/166155

Comment: Users who exclusively use the mobile app are particularly affected by this since they can't see deleted posts or comments on them. I suspect SE's response to that is that the mobile app is designed to augment not replace main site usage.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4722/how-can-we-encourage-posters-to-fix-their-questions

Comment: @DoubleAA Given all the bugs with the iOS version, and how long they’ve gone with A) existing, and B) no response from the SE team, I gather they’re trying to phase out the mobile app in favor of the site. I don’t know why I still insist on using the app anyway, though now that I’ve hit 10K I might start using the normal website more.

Comment: @DonielF The app, tailored for smartphones, is more readable and fast than the mobile version of the website.